Запятая в "потратить деньги куда надо"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении
"Должны потратить деньги куда надо"
нужна ли запятая перед "куда"?

Правильно:
Должны потратить деньги куда надо.
Куда надо – устойчивое сочетание, имеет значение одного слова (= по назначению), поэтому запятая не ставится.
Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка
Куда надо.  Прост. По назначению; именно туда, куда следует.
Оскорблённый в лучших музыкальных чувствах, директор (клуба) 
сел и написал «куда надо» о музыкантах, которые отказались 
обслуживать население (Э. Графов. Арфа включает «скоростя»). 
— Ну, не очень-то. Иди куда надо… Мне очень не хотелось идти 
«куда надо», но тут наше путешествие окончилось. В отделении 
оказался всего один дежурный милиционер (Л. Гартунг. Нельзя 
забывать…)

Карта слов
Получил деньги, вроде, потратил куда надо, в карман себе не положил – заказать материалы, завтра выдать зарплату, сломались инструменты – купить, а давайте ещё и вот это производить – круто! покупаем новый станок, а лучше два.
И.А. Кривогузов, Миллион для себя. Как создать надежное финансовое будущее, 2020
